# Forge Viewer dwg import scaling

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are trying to use the Forge Viewer to display several autocad models within a building shell(also Autocad) in 2D.
We are stuck on the scaling and positioning of the 2D DWG models. It seems like all of the loaded models scale to roughly
the same size, regardless of the dwg's coordinates or unit.
We have tried using the applyScaling: option (among other options) but it does not seem to have any effect.
One strange thing we noticed is if we use FBX models the models are all correct but if we used 3D DWGS we get the same problem and
all of the models are scaled to roughly the same size after loading.

See referenced github project below for a demonstration project.  (Note: you'll need to reference your own models in the project)

What are we doing wrong here?

https://github.com/Eholling/APS-Viewer-Scaling-Issues

We tried using scaling options, import model and existing examples.
Tried to change/scale source drawing units as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the DWG models are normalized to some hard-coded bounds during their conversion in the Model Derivative service. However, the original dimension info is always stored in the model's metadata so you can use that data to make sure that all the aggregated drawings are scaled accordingly.

Try this:

- Go to https://aps-simple-viewer-nodejs.autodesk.io/#dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cGV0cmJyb3otc2FtcGxlcy9yb2JvdF9oYW5kbGluZ19jZWxsLmR3Zw
- Open the dev tools console
- Type `NOP_VIEWER.model.getBoundingBox()`; you'll see that the "viewer dimensions" of the drawing are 210x148mm (A5 standard)
- Type `NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().metadata.page_dimensions`; you'll see that there's additional information about the original drawing such as `logical_width`, `logical_height`, `plot_width`, `plot_height`, or `source_to_logical_xform`; when you check how these values are set for your own DWG files, it should be possible to figure out the scale factor that should be applied to the drawings to keep them in the same scale